# How can I get a DateTime value with Bindings? (WPF-MVVM)

Tags: wpf, datetime, mvvm, binding

I would like something like this:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" />
```

Is there any control or easy solution for this? (I use MVVM.)

Comment: Are you asking for a DatePicker control? Or are you asking about how to do a binding with a DateTime? Probably need to clarify your question.

Comment: Im sorry if it wasn't clear. Im asking about how to do a binding with a DateTime type, like the WPF Toolkit DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case you must have only property `StartDate` in ViewModel and it will be working.

And when you change date in the DatePicker, it will be automatically reflected in the property StartDate in ViewModel class.

Simple ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _startDate = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get { return _startDate; }
            set { _startDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");  }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Simple View:

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>    
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" />        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) (note: CodePlex is down/slow at the time of writing).