# Datepicker MVVM not updating value when binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new on MVVM and I am trying to migrate a Winform program to WPF MVVM(.NET6). In my View I have the following control defined on xmal:

```
 <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Fecha}"/>
```

On the ViewModel I have the field Fecha with his property plus the constructor that initialize Fecha:

```
public TransformarMTViewModel()
{
    Fecha = DateTime.Now; //it doesnt work updating the view
    RutaArchivo = "Replace the textbox"; //it work updating the view
}

public string RutaArchivo
{
    get { return rutaArchivo; }
    set
    {
        if (value != rutaArchivo)
        {
            rutaArchivo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public DateTime Fecha
{
    get { return fecha; }
    set
    {
        if (value != fecha)
        {
            fecha = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The OnPropertyChanged() is defined as follows:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

For some reasson that I dont understand when I load the view the only updated control is the textbox, but the  DatePicker keep saying "select date", If I change the content on the DatePicker it doesnt update the value of the property neither.

Edit: In case you are wondering I already tried other solutions that I saw on StackOverflow without any luck.

Comment: Do you inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`?
See the answer of this post here, which has a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959543/how-can-i-get-a-datetime-value-with-bindings-wpf-mvvm

Comment: Did you remember to set your `DataContext` in your View to be your ViewModel? Also, I would remove the `if value not equal` conditions in your setters, and simply set the value along with `OnPropertyChanged()` because it doesn't add any extra protection.

Comment: @RolandDeschain looks exactly the same as my code but for some reasson only the Datepicker dont work.

Comment: @TamBui yes I set the datacontext on the view on xaml format

Comment: looks like the issue is because I am using a style on it and I need to bind the text there?

Comment: Instead of giving us snippets that are not giving us the full picture (especially with no xaml posted), please try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just your `RutaArchivo` and `SelectedDate` properties in a simplified UI. Then we can see what's wrong. This appears to be a plain binding-related issue, which should be simple to resolve.

Comment: @TamBui yup I am sorry, I forgot that I was using a template and it was causing the issue, as soon as I removed it worked.